# Superfish jQuery menu: 3rd level always open when 1st level hovered

Tags: jquery, superfish

I'm trying to achieve a menu where you can hover the first level and the second **and** the third level (of the first item in second level) opens.

I thought it would be possible with the `onHide`-callback function of [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#options) or with the `pathClass`-argument but it failed so far.

My menu looks something like this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnxaE/3/)

In the example on jsfiddle it should be hovered `ASDF` and the 3rd level would open with `bla 1` and `bla 2`

Any hints how this problem could be solved would be appreciated.

Comment: The third level is not opening for me. Using the newest version of Firefox here.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of jQuery and Superfish on your own server?

Comment: yes, jquery 1.7.1 and superfish 1.4.8

Comment: Does your example work on jsfiddle for you?

Comment: Perhaps you should double-check your version numbers. And make sure the piece of code is called correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `onShow` callback to do what you want:

```
$('.mainnav>ul').superfish({
    onShow: function() {
        $( this ).find( ".sf-with-ul:first" ).closest("li").trigger("mouseenter");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/XnxaE/7/

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I was trying to achieve. There's still one problem: if you hover over ASDF->BLUBB->ASDF the 3rd level hides again. But I think I should get that done.